# In output, echo command printed new line when after printed variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell

This is my small bash script code and i want to print the number of files created in the directory :

```
#! /bin/sh
home_dir=/home/var/foo
Count= ls /$home_dir|wc -l
echo -e "$Count files are existed in the directory $home_dir"
exit 0
```

My expected output is :

```
9 files are existed in the directory /home/var/foo
```

but i got the below output:

```
9
 files are existed in the directory /home/var/foo
```

can you help what went wrong in my above code? Also please suggest if this is the correct way to print the number of files in the directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
Count=$(ls /$xml_dir|wc -l)
```

Comment: This works because it actually captures the output of the command. In OP's posted code, `Count` has no meaning as a variable. It's equivalent to `ls /$home_dir|wc -l; echo -e " files are existed in the directory $home_dir"`

Answer (score 0):

To print on the same line

```
echo -ne "$Count files are existed in the directory $home_dir"
```

Add argument n to the echo.

Comment: This just removes the newline from the end